# How can you put items on one line and center them?

Tags: itemize

**Is there an easy way to make the items appear horizontally and not vertically and also be centered?**

I have tried the following code but the points are squahed to the left side and there is no space in between them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize*}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

I am thinking something like the one below where **o** is the "dot" made.

(space from the left side) **o** Item 1    (space here)   **o** Item 2

Comment: @leandriis, almost but the problem is that they use enumerate and I am looking for itemize. As I wrote in my question I am looking to have the black dots and not numbers there.

Comment: I edit my question to clarify more.

Comment: @leandriis, I have edited the question with my code and what I want to accomplish.

Comment: You could use the `itemjoin` key to customize the horizontal distance between adjacent items. Seomthing like `\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize*}[itemjoin={\hspace{1cm}}]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item 3
  \item Item 4
\end{itemize*}

\end{document}` or any other width of your choice should work.

Comment: @leandriis, thanks that looks better but the first item is stlll glued to the left side

Comment: You can use the `before` key to add horizontal white space before the first item in your list. (`\begin{itemize*}[before={\hspace{2cm}},itemjoin={\hspace{1cm}}]`)

Comment: @leandriis, wow thanks! Looks much better! Would be cool if this could be done automatically so 2cm is not hardcoded but that will do for now! Thanks again.

Comment: How wide should this automatic indetation be?

Comment: How can this be a duplicate of the linked question, where centering is not touched upon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several choices, of which I present two. The new environment would be my choice.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\newenvironment{centeritemize*}[1][]
  {\par\centering\begin{itemize*}[itemjoin=\quad,#1]}
  {\end{itemize*}\par}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize*}[
  itemjoin=\quad,
  before=\hspace*{\fill},
  after=\hspace*{\labelwidth}\hspace*{-\labelsep}\hspace*{\fill},
]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item3
\end{itemize*}

\begin{centeritemize*}
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
  \item Item3
\end{centeritemize*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want some vertical space above and below the list, you can do

```
\newenvironment{centeritemize*}[1][]
  {\begin{center}\begin{itemize*}[itemjoin=\quad,#1]}
  {\end{itemize*}\end{center}}
```

and this shows why using a new environment is better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! How can I add more space between the items vertically? Do I edit `itemjoin` with something like `\qquad`?

Comment: @Clone Sorry, but I don't understand: do you want the item stacked vertically? Please, be clearer with your question.

Comment: Woops, sorry I meant horisontally. Like, how can I increase the spacing horizontally so that there would be more space between items 1 2 and 3 for instance?

Comment: @Clone `itemjoin=\qquad` or `itemjoin=\hspace*{3cm}` (or whatever length you like).

Comment: Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the `before` and `after` keys from enumitem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize*}[itemjoin=\quad, before=\null\hfill, after=\hskip1.5em\hfill]
  \item Item 1
  \item Item 2
\item Item3
\end{itemize*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg: I've just tested  it, but my code (with the `\hspace` found by trial and error) is better centred – the difference in length of the white spaces on each side is measured to 0.2pt.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\itemtab}{\hspace{\tabcolsep}\textbullet\hspace{\itemsep}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{\itemtab}l@{\itemtab}l}
  Item 1 & Item 2
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```